# Use a sass file with all my @use, but it says my variables are undefined

Tags: sass

I have a file `main.scss` with 2 @use

```
@use 'components/variables';
@use 'components/card';
```

Here is the code in `components/_variables.scss`

```
$bg-color: red;

$color:(
  text: yellow
);
```

Here is the code in `components/_card.scss`

```
body{
  background-color: $bg-color;
  color: map-get($color, text );
}
```

And here is the error I get when compiling

```
Error: Undefined variable.
  ╷
2 │   background-color: $bg-color;
  │                     ^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  sass/components/_card.scss 2:21  @use
  sass/main.scss 1:1               root stylesheet
```

I know the code don't have much sense with a variable and a get-map, but I'm trying to learn Sass and I don't understand why my variables are not imported correctly. Can someone explain it to me? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@use is unfortunately only supported by DartSASS yet.
You need to import a different version of SASS in order to make it work.
[@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use).

Comment: but can't I use @import instead for the moment? I just need my variables to work from an independant file.

Comment: Sure you can, but `@use` imports only the portion you use, while `@import` imports all. There's nothing wrong with it though, it will not make any difference to the compiled CSS.

Comment: Finally, It worked with import. Thanks for the explanation about @use :)